# draw on top of cameras in Unity Android Cardboard

Tags: android, google-cardboard

I'd like to create a menu button for a google cardboard unity app running on android that is positioned in one of the corners of the screen so that users can press a menu button outside of VR (with their finger). The button would be outside of the area viewable when in the cardboard viewer. The app will have two modes: a standard touch-based gui navigation with things like an instructions screen with contact & share buttons, and a VR mode.

To do this, I added a new gui camera that I have my instructions screen and menu button in, and have its depth set above the standard google cardboard cameras, but I can never see it when the CardboardMain script is in VR mode. I suspect it's because the VR mode is drawing outside of Unity on top of any other camera. It shows up correctly when I change the CardboardMain's VRModeEnababled to false.

Comment: Why do you even want to makea separate camera? You can have the cardbooard camera rig be in VRModeEnabled false and have a regular menu as in any other app. Once the cuser clicks "start and put headset on" you set VRModeEnabled to true and hide the menu.

Comment: When VRModeEnabled is false, everything works as expected, I can use or not use another camera to add a regular menu. NGui utilizes a 3rd ortho camera as a convenience. However, I can't seem to control much when VRModeEnabled is true. I would still like to display a menu button in the corner that doesn't get barrel warped in VR mode, and is positioned relative to the screen edge. Many viewers have an array of buttons to switch between VR and non VR mode, for instance.